# Feature to be installed depending upon user selection using checkbox in wix installer

Tags: checkbox, wix, windows-installer

I have created the dialog in wix which has 3 checkbox. user can select either one or all at a time. depending upon the selection of check box the feature needs to be selected and installed.

Suppose I have 3 application (ABC, DEF, GHI) and these are defined in the feature with condition statement.

```
<Control Id="ABC" Type="CheckBox" X="190" Y="110" Width="50" Height="17" Property="PQR" CheckBoxValue="1" Text="ABC">
```

similarly for other 2 application also I have the checkbox control.

Now I have 3 features like below.

```
<Feature Id="abc" Title="ABC" Level="0">
  <Condition Level="1"><![CDATA[PQR="1"]]></Condition>
  <ComponentRef Id="InstallABC"/>
</Feature>
```

I don't want to add the PQR as property in product.wxs because I don' want the checkbox to be selected by default.

Is it possible to do it using custom action.

Any answer or suggestions will be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

You need to publish the feature as AddLocal and explicitly you need to call Remove All before adding AddLocal.
On Next button you need to write these code.

```
<Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="248" Y="243" Width="56" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="!(loc.WixUINext)" >
          <Publish Event="Remove" Value="ALL" Order="1">1</Publish>
          <Publish Event="AddLocal" Value="Feature1">CheckBox1="1"</Publish>
          <Publish Event="AddLocal" Value="Feature2">CheckBox2="1"</Publish>
</Control>
```

Next the feature will look like this.

```
<Feature Id="Feature1" Title="ABC">
  <ComponentRef Id="InstallABC"/>
</Feature>
```

> Note:- Feature should not have the Level Element, Also Don't add any Property for your CheckBox explicitly anywhere like Product.wxs.